Compare/sync current drive contents to specific previous Time Machine snapshot
I have an external SSD that is attached to my MacBook Air whenever I'm at my desk (since the tiny 120GB internal drive cannot be upgraded).
I recently discovered that the external drive had become corrupted, so I purchased a new one, and was able to to migrate most files successfully from the old drive to the new drive using rsync. In the process, I found that a number of files had "vanished", and I was able to rescue these from my backup.
My concern now is that maybe other files have gone missing, and I would like to compare the contents of the drive with some previous Time Machine monthly snapshots, to get a list of files that are in the snapshot but not in the current drive. Then I can work out if they were files I had actually intended to delete, or if they just got lost and need to be restored.
I could purchase another SSD, copy the whole Time Machine snapshot to that, and then use "rsync -ni --ignore-existing" to generate the file list comparing the two SSDs.
But is there a better way, where I can just generate this information directly from interacting with the Time Machine snapshot?
My first thought was to try rsync but I didn't expect it would work with a Time Machine backup, and after a long wait nothing was happening. I know tmutil can compare the most recent snapshot with the current state - but can it do that for a specified previous snapshot, and for a specific volume only? Or is there some other way?
Thank you!
(I am on a 2018 MacBook Air running Sonoma 14.6.1 - my Time Machine backup is on a 4th generation Time Capsule, usually connected wirelessly but currently connected wired)

I found a way round this.

Make sure that the relevant snapshot is actually mounted. The only reliable way to do this is to open it in Finder. Once you have mounted the sparsebundle, all the snapshots will show up in /Volumes/.timemachine - but they are not actually mounted until you touch them in Finder.

Use CrcCheckCopy to compare the backup and the current drive. Tried a couple of GUI tools but they always crashed or stalled. CrcCheckCopy works on the command line and actually seemed able to read the backup in reasonable time:
https://www.starmessagesoftware.com/crccheckcopy/


